# PHP dynamic table header and dynamic table rows based on header - tried everything

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, html-table

I am trying to build a editable table with dynamic headers and dynamic rows based on header, but I lost my way in the process.
I got the dynamic headers:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <table class='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Emails</th>
                <?php
                    include("../connection/connection.php");


                    $get_title = "SELECT DISTINCT(title) FROM attendance";
                    $query1 = mysqli_query($con,$get_title);        

                    if ($query1) {
                        # code...
                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
                            # code...
                            $title[] = $row['title'];

                        }
                        $count = count($title);
                        for ($i=0; $i <$count ; $i++) { 
                            # code...
                            echo "<th>".$title[$i]."</th>";

                        }

                    }

                ?>

            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 

            $get_emails = "SELECT * FROM subjects";
            $query2 = mysqli_query($con,$get_emails);

            if ($query2) {
                # code...
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {
                    # code...
                    $emails = $row['email'];
                    $id = $row['id'];

                    $get_name = "SELECT * FROM users";
                    $query3 = mysqli_query($con,$get_name);

                    if ($query3) {
                        # code...
                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query3)) {
                            # code...
                            $fullname = $row['user_fullname'];

                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td contenteditable>".$id."</td>";
                            echo "<td contenteditable>".$fullname."</td>";
                            echo "<td contenteditable>".$emails."</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                    } else {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td contenteditable>".$id."</td>";
                            echo "<td contenteditable></td>";
                            echo "<td contenteditable>".$emails."</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                    }

                }

            } else {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td contenteditable></td>";
                echo "<td contenteditable></td>";
                echo "<td contenteditable></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I need to echo the table td which would be dynamic based on the headers after the emails - td inside the tr.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem you have is that the array element isn't going to be called `title` but rather `DISTINCT(title)` because you didn't alias it as something else, the code below shows it being aliased back as title, and as well eliminating what appears to be an unnecessary loop.

```
$get_title = "SELECT DISTINCT(title) title FROM attendance";
$query1 = mysqli_query($con,$get_title);        

if ($query1) {
    # code...
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
        # code...
        echo "<th>".$title[$i]$row['title']."</th>";
    }
}
```